# Get the Attributes of every item in the Document Directory iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdocumentdirectory, nsattributedescription

I've been trying to get **Attributes** such as File Type, Creation Date, File Size of all the items in the **Document Directory**.

Here is the code that I've been using, but it returns me just "**NSFileTypeDirectory**"

```
 let filemgr = FileManager.default
        
        
     do
     {
        let attribs: NSDictionary? = try filemgr.attributesOfItem(
            atPath: documentDirectoryPath!) as NSDictionary
        if let fileattribs = attribs
     {
            let type = fileattribs["NSFileType"] as! String
            print("File type \(type)")
     }
     }
     catch
     {
            print(error)
     }
```

I think its returning the attributes of Document folder.

Comment: That's because you are passing the path of `Documents Directory` and not the path of _file inside documents directory_ . You need to pass the complete path of file inside the documents directory for which you want the attributes

Comment: Unrelated but `attributesOfItem(atPath` returns non-optional `[FileAttributeKey : Any]` **not** optional `NSDictionary` and the `error` variable is never used.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentdirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
let filePath = documentdirectory?.appendingPathComponent("your file name").path

do {
  let fileAttribute = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath!)
  let fileSize = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.size] as! Int64
  let fileType = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.type] as! String
  let filecreationDate = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as! Date

} catch let error {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @KarthikeyanBose's code: To get the infos for *all* the files in the *Documents* directory do this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

if let documentsURLs = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    do {
        let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsURLs.path)

        for fileName in fileNames {
            let fileURL = documentsURLs.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

            let fileAttribute = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
            let fileSize = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.size] as! Int64
            let fileType = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.type] as! String
            let filecreationDate = fileAttribute[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as! Date
            let fileExtension = fileURL.pathExtension;

            print("Name: \(fileName), Size: \(fileSize), Type: \(fileType), Date: \(filecreationDate), Extension: \(fileExtension)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
} //Handle this "else" error too, even though this really shouldn't happen
```

This code prints e.g.:

```
Name: Deadpool.png, Size: 39225, Type: NSFileTypeRegular, Date: 2019-05-27 11:03:03 +0000, Extension: png
```