# Determining file type in Swift

Tags: swift, filesystems, foundation

Because directories are files in macOS and Linux too, I try to determine what type of file it is.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import Foundation

let filePath = "/Users/Sample/test.ext"

if FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: filePath) {
    /// File does exist at this location
}
```

However, this code does not say whether the file is a regular file or a directory. I thought about using [`fileType()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1416809-filetype) to get the exact file type.

Can anyone please help me? I tried a bit but I don't get it working and I am new to Swift.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi to whoever wrote a comment that disappeared now. This is not a duplicate, I asked about how determine the file type. The question in the duplicate box is about if a file is a directory but there are other file types too (see Accessing File Type Attributes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/fileattributetype#1788787).

Comment: Your whole question is talking about determining if the file is a directory or not. If that’s not your actual question then please edit your question to clarify what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Title says “determining file type”, body “I try to determine what type of file it is” and “this code does not say whether the file is a regular file”. Don’t know what I should change?

Comment: Your question has *"Because directories are files in macOS and Linux too"* and more importantly *"However, this code does not say whether the file is a regular file or a directory."*. So it reads as if the file type you are asking about is whether it's a directory or a regular file. Update your question to include examples of different file types you want to know about if it's more than "directory" or "regular file". BTW - I'm not the only one that thinks the duplicate applies at the moment. Once you clarify the question, it can be reopened.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what to clarify. Even if you take the nitty gritty and say "determine if normal file or directory" then the alleged duplicate will answer if the file is a directory but still not if a normal file. As I said, looking to see if it's a directory is still and will be ever the wrong way to see if it's a normal file or not. And it doesn't matter if anyone agrees with you or not, quantity is not quality.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410452-attributesofitem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258342/get-the-attributes-of-every-item-in-the-document-directory-ios-swift